# FastAPI 422 Unprocessable Entity POST

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, fastapi

I have a FastAPI app with a POST method and I am trying to send a relatively large string with many words. Basically, it's a ChatGPT prompt with some text that needs to be rewritten by ChatGPT.
The problem is when I send this text, I get the error:

> 422 Unprocessable Entity

However, when I send the exact same text but as a text file, that then is read and written into string variable and then passed to ChatGPT, it works perfectly fine. Also, the POST method that takes a string as a parameter, works fine too if the string is relatively small. How can I fix it? I need to be able to send a large chunk of text without uploading it as a file.

FastAPI code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi import File, UploadFile
import g4f

app = FastAPI()

origins = ["*"]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

g4f.debug.logging = True
g4f.check_version = False


class Prompt(BaseModel):
    text: str


@app.get("/")
def root():
    return {"message": "some text whatever"}


@app.post("/prompt_text")
def create_prompt(prompt: Prompt):
    response = g4f.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": str(prompt)}],
    )

    return {'result': response}


@app.post("/prompt_file")
def create_prompt(prompt: str = None, file: UploadFile = File(None)):
    if file is not None:
        file_content = file.file.read().decode('utf-8')
        prompt_content = file_content
    else:
        prompt_content = prompt

    response = g4f.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt_content}],
    )

    return {'result': response}
```

Comment: The body of the 422 error will tell you exactly which fields are missing/fails validation. Without seeing what you're sending to the endpoint it's impossible for someone to say what you're missing; however, when you have a file upload, the other fields either have to be POST (Form) values or query strings - and if you want it to be nullable, it should be defined as Optional as well (or `prompt: str | None = None`)

Answer (score 1):

The variable `prompt` is declared as `Prompt class` instead of sending `prompt` you need to send the attribute `text` like this:

```
response = g4f.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": str(prompt.text)}],
    )
```

and the payload should be like this:

```
{
"text":"your text"
}
```

Comment: nothing changed, the error remains